# Type 'io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver' does not have type parameters

Tags: java, testing, webdriver, appium

I'm working on an Appium project and trying to declare an AppiumDriver object with a type parameter for WebElement.

Error message: Type 'io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver' does not have type parameters public AppiumDriver driver; WebElement giving error.

Here's the code snippet:

```
package org.example;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class LoginTest {

    public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
```

I have already imported the necessary classes for AppiumDriver and WebElement. I'm using the latest version of the Appium Java client library in my project.
Could anyone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? Am I missing any additional configuration or dependencies?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you share error message itself

Comment: `AppiumDriver` does not take generics e.g you cannot use `<T>`, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov here is the error message: Type 'io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver' does not have type parameters public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver; WebElement giving error.

Comment: Please update your post with error message